# Normalizing paths with unknown parent references

Tags: vb.net, path, normalization

### Problem statement

My current project requires dealing with a lot of unix-style paths, most importantly joining paths and normalizing paths.

By normalizing, I mean removing all references to the current directory (`.`), references to the parent directory (`..`) and redundant forward slashes (`//`), while preserving the "meaning" of the original path.

For example: the path `/foo/bar` and `/foo/./bar` and `/foo/baz/../bar` all point to the same directory. However, doing a simple string comparison would evidently indicate that they are different paths. That's why I'm trying to normalize paths so that they are all treated the same.

The code to do this was actually not terribly difficult to write. You can find my code at the bottom of the question. But there is still 1 problem that I'm having trouble with.

Currently, it is possible for a user to enter a path that looks like this:

```
input:      /../../../foo/bar
normalized: /foo/bar
```

Because this is an absolute path, it correctly resolves to `foo/bar` in the root (`/`) directory.

However, when the input is a relative path, I can't possibly backtrack the amount of steps required because I don't know the names of the parent directories.

```
input:      ../../../foo/bar
normalized: foo/bar
```

Imagine that the full path was `/a/b/c/d/../../../foo/bar`, in which case the algorithm produces:

```
input:      /a/b/c/d/../../../foo/bar
normalized: /a/foo/bar
```

The problem arises when, for whatever reason, the path is split into `/a/b/c/d` and `../../../foo/bar`.

```
input:      /a/b/c/d/
input:      ../../../foo/bar
normalized: /a/b/c/d
normalized: foo/bar

joined: /a/b/c/d/foo/bar
```

As you can see, the path has lost its original meaning when the normalized output values are joined back together. This would not have occurred if I didn't remove the leading parent references.

So I guess I have 3 options in case of the relative path with unknown parent references:

1. remove leading parent references, even though the result is technically wrong
2. keep leading parent references, even though the result is technically not normalized
3. throw an error

I'm hoping that some genius can come up with a better idea. But if not, what would you do?

### Code

I haven't yet tested my code for every possible use case, but it should be relatively (pun intended) stable.

```
Public MustInherit Class UnixPath

    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets whether the specified path is an absolute path.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Shared Function IsAbsolute(path As String) As Boolean
        Return path.StartsWith(UnixPath.Separator, StringComparison.InvariantCulture)
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Normalizes a string path, taking care of '..' and '.' parts.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Shared Function Normalize(path As String) As String
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(path) Then
            Return String.Empty
        End If
        Dim oldPath = path.Split(New Char() {UnixPath.Separator}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        Dim newPath As New Stack(Of String)
        Dim skipCount As Integer = 0

        For i = oldPath.GetUpperBound(0) To oldPath.GetLowerBound(0) Step -1
            If String.Equals(oldPath(i), UnixPath.CurrentDirectory, StringComparison.InvariantCulture) Then
                Continue For
            ElseIf String.Equals(oldPath(i), UnixPath.ParentDirectory, StringComparison.InvariantCulture) Then
                skipCount += 1
            ElseIf skipCount > 0 Then
                skipCount -= 1
            Else
                newPath.Push(oldPath(i))
            End If
        Next

        If UnixPath.IsAbsolute(path) Then
            Return UnixPath.Join(UnixPath.Separator, UnixPath.Join(newPath.ToArray))
        Else
            For i = 1 To skipCount
                newPath.Push(UnixPath.ParentDirectory)
            Next
            Return UnixPath.Join(newPath.ToArray)
        End If
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Combines an array of string paths.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Shared Function Join(ParamArray paths As String()) As String
        Dim builder As New StringBuilder
        Dim count = paths.GetUpperBound(0)

        For i = paths.GetLowerBound(0) To count
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(paths(i)) Then
                Continue For
            End If
            builder.Append(paths(i).TrimEnd(UnixPath.Separator))
            If i = count Then
                Exit For
            End If

            builder.Append(UnixPath.Separator)
        Next

        Return builder.ToString
    End Function

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property CurrentDirectory As String
        Get
            Return "."
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property ParentDirectory As String
        Get
            Return ".."
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Separator As Char
        Get
            Return "/"c
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: By the way, I'm leaning towards placing the leading parent references back if their names cannot be determined. Cons or pros anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not preserve meaning of your original path by removing `..`, only by removing repeated `.` and `/`. It is not clear what you are trying to do, though. It could be that you really don't need to "normalize" your path this way.

Anyway, here is a thought:

```
Dim inputPath As String = "/../../../foo/bar"
Dim outputPath As String = inputPath.Replace(".", "").Replace("..", "")
Dim outputPathLength As Integer
Do
  outputPathLength = outputPath.Length
  outputPath = outputPath.Replace("//", "/")
Loop Until outputPathLength = outputPath.Length
```

For a better implementation - one that would also account for your case #2, and more, you should probably use regular expressions.

**EDIT:** that would probably be considered hacks by some, but here is another option:

```
Dim inputPath As String = "../../../foo/bar"
Dim outPath As String = IO.Path.GetFullPath(IO.Path.Combine("C:\", inputPath))
Dim newPath As String = outPath.Substring(outPath.IndexOf("\") + 1).Replace("\", "/")
If inputPath.StartsWith("/") Then newPath = "/" & newPath
MsgBox(newPath)
```

It uses file system to normalize a path, and convert back to unix style. Works for all test cases above.

Comment: Hello! I've added an example to my problem statement to better explain what I'm trying to do. The code that I've attached is pretty much complete, although I'd be interested to see a working alternative that uses regexes.

Comment: Oh and I will preserve the meaning in case of the rooted path, because the parent directory of the root directory defaults to the root directory.

Comment: @StevenDotNet: I did not realize those were referring to root, in this case you are right. It's just that simply removing `..` would not cut it (for example, when `..` is in the middle of the path). Anyway, check my edit - perhaps, this is what you wanted.

Comment: I think I'm still not making myself clear on the issue. Imagine that the full path is `/a/b/c/d/../../../foo/bar`. After looping it through my algorithm, that would produce `/a/foo/bar`. The problem is when I receive only a part of the full path, in which case the original meaning would be lost if I remove the parent references.

Comment: @StevenDotNet: Mine also would work out to `/a/foo/bar`, but it's way shorter. Could you elaborate in your original question on this part: `when I receive only a part of the full path, in which case the original meaning would be lost`?

Comment: I've added another example that should hopefully clarify what I meant, but it's getting a little long-winded.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more that I'm convinced that I should just keep the leading `..` if the actual name cannot be determined.

Comment: @StevenDotNet: I'll try to explain our discussion on cars. My point - `ok here is your broken car, here is how to fix it`. You say: `yeah, but if I split my car into 2 parts, the fix does not work... what should I do?` Bottom line, you cannot get something from nothing. If your path is either split or not split, and you want to optimize without definitively knowing its nature, there is nothing you can do.

Comment: That's more or less the point I was making about the unknown parent directories. I decided to keep the `..` parts after all if a valid name cannot be determined. I'm pretty happy with the results so far.